# viewing sql server database from a remote machine

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Please I am new to sql database, I have been using mysql and php but the new systems I am working on where developed with ASP.net.

Usually I can access phymadmin even from a remote machine through localhost on an apache system.

Are there any such resources for accessing or exporting sql databases from a remote machine?

Already I can access our app locally by going to localhost/appname from the browser of the local machine but I to be able to view database tables also remotely.

Thanks, I will appreciate all the help I can get

Comment: Install SQL Server Management Studio (which is part of SQL Server).

Comment: Or if you need it, SQL Server Management Studio is available as a standalone product, see here for the latest version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: Sql Server management studio is already on the host machine. I just want to access it from the remote machine also like i do with php.

Comment: @user3582815 you need to install Sql Server Management Studio [SSMS] on the machine you want to access the database from e.g. your local machine to connect to the server.  Or you can write custom code to connect to the database and query as desired. SSMS being installed on the server doesn't help you administer the database from your local machine.

Answer (score -3):

Connect both the systems with a common network. Then use the ip address of the ahine in which database is available as localhost for another machine. Eg. if theip address of machine which contains database is 168.158.14.2. Then go to browser of another machine and type the web address as 168.158.14.2/phpmyadmin

Comment: How is that in any way shape or form useful for SQL Server?